# Can someone explain why this ruby code for finding anagrams works?

Tags: ruby, function

Here's the line:

```
words.group_by { |word| word.downcase.chars.sort }.values
```

`words` is an array of words that are then sorted into groups if they share the same letters as another word in the original array.  Can someone go down the line and explain how this works?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, let's go through the methods one by one:

**`group_by`**: is a method that takes an `Enumerable` (in this case an Array) and a block. It passes each value in the array to the block, and then looks at the block's results. It then returns a Hash, where the keys are the results of the block, and the values are arrays of the original input that had the same result.

**`downcase`**: takes a string and makes it all lowercase

**`chars`**: converts a string into an array of characters

**`sort`**: sorts a collection

**`values`**: returns just the values of a `Hash`.

With those definitions, let's return to your code:

```
words.group_by { |word| word.downcase.chars.sort }.values
```

> "Take each `word` in the array of **`words`**, make it lowercase, then sort its
>   letters into alphabetical order. The words that contain exactly the same
>   letters will have the same sorted result, so we can group them into a
>   Hash of Arrays, with the sorted letters as the key and the Array of
>   matching words as the value. We don't actually care what the actual letters
>   are, just the words that share them, so we take only the Arrays (the `values`)."

To break it down with an example:

```
words = %w[throw worth threw Live evil]
  # => [ 'throw', 'worth', 'threw', 'Live', 'evil' ]
words_hash = words.group_by {|word| word.downcase.chars.sort} 
  # => {
  #      'eilv'  => [ 'evil', 'Live' ],
  #      'ehrtw' => [ 'threw'],
  #      'hortw' => [ 'throw', 'worth']
  #    }

words_hash.values
  # => [['evil', 'Live'], ['threw'], ['throw', 'worth']]
```

Comment: I edited the example to add in the chars method within the words_hash assignment.

Comment: @user2106071 any chance you could accept this answer? :)